# Tabs inside tabs layout

Tags: flash, apache-flex, user-interface, tabs, navigation

Before I jump into code, I'd like to ask you guys for the best way to do this.

First, take a look at this image:
[image: Interface]

Now let me quickly explain how this interface should work:
-If you click any of the bottom buttons/tabs, the top buttons/tabs and content will change according to the selection.
So, when you click "Overview" at the bottom, you will be presented with a new menu at top, displaying the options as you can see in the image. These options at the top will again change what content is shown.

How would you do this?

Also, I'll mention that this window will be scaled to fit window, so I need to be able to place the tabs/buttons where I need them (for example, ll but the last (on both top and bottom bar) to the left, and the last to the right).

My first idea was to simply use a tabNavigator with a tabNavigator inside it. But I feel more comfortable asking you guys if there are any better ways to do this, or if this is a good way.

Oh, I'm using Flex (Flash Builder 4.6).

Any tips and ideas are welcome.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure that's good UX, but other than that there are as many solutions to this as there are developers. It all depends on how you're going to wire the communication in your application. Looking at your screenshot I would go in the direction of two separate ButtonBars with one driving the others dataProvider and the second driving the main content, possibly by using a common presentation model.

Comment: How would I go about making the first buttonBar drive the other buttonbars dataProvider? It seems it only wants to bind to a viewStack. Should I have one viewstack with the buttonBar #2 inside? And those buttons again should drive another viewstack which is the content area?

Comment: For example: `menu2.dataProvider="{menu1.selectedItem.children}"` should already do the trick.

Comment: What I did now was to make one buttonBar, assign it to viewStack1. Inside viewstack1 I have a new viewstack2 and a new buttonBar2 which controlls this viewstack2. So I end up having one new viewStack and buttonBar for each meny item in the first buttonBar (bottom). But I dont think this is what you mean?

Comment: Hmm.. I seem to have a problem here. I want to attach a child to one of the viewstack pages. I've made a group inside the one I want, and gave it an ID. but I cant access this ID when the all is loading. How can I preload these groups to make them available from outside the right viewstack?

Comment: You shouldn't be accessing views directly. Use events, controllers, mediators or whatever to communicate between components. That said, I don't know ViewStack very well: it's an old mx component and it doensn't do anything that I can't write in a few lines using States.

Comment: Hmmm. I might have to look at a different approach? I'm gonna load in swf content, and panorama renders, and lots of stuff like that, so I need to be able to add childs to it, and access it easily. Garh, this is why I should participate in an flex course, to learn all these bits and pieces that I still struggle with..

Comment: Or read a good book ;)

Comment: Indeed ;)
Well, thanks a lot for your help mate. =) Got any good books to recommend?

Comment: I like [the one by Farata](http://www.amazon.com/Enterprise-Development-Flex-Practices-Developers/dp/059615416X) but it's very targeted at enterprise development, which may not be what you're after. Other than that there's alway the traditional cookbooks if you're more of a beginner.

Comment: Enterprise is exactly what I need :) Thanks, I'll check it out!
I'm not a beginner, as I've done quite a lot of different projects, but I do lack some of the basic understanding from time to time. I get stuch when I do stuff I've never done before ;)

Comment: Never heard the term RIA before! But I guess that's exactly what I'm doing here ^^ Feel free to add me to skype if you want. I'll promise not to disturb you ;) Stianbl2

Comment: Well it's another one of those buzzwords from a few years back. Should 've picked something more lasting :(